# Run-time error 13: Type mismatch while reading cell value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I know just basic to excel. I have got huge excel sheet from client . I am trying to explain with sample data what i want. Here is the input data in one sheet

[image]

I need output like below

[image]

I tried below program

```
Sub TestCustomMerge()

Dim row2&, row4&, val1&, val2&, val3&
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

row2 = 2
row4 = 4

'// error at below line i.e. Run-time error  13: Type mismatch
val1 = Cells(row2, 1).Value

' // Also I am not getting how concatenate value of Cells(row2, 2) and Cells(row4, 2)
' // so that they appear as it is (not in a single line)
val2 = Cells(row2, 2).Value

Cells(row2, 1).Cells(row4, 1).Merge
Cells(row2, 1).Value = val1
Cells(row2, 2).Cells(row4, 2).Merge

'// set concatenated value here
Cells(row2, 2).Value = val2



Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

But it gives `Run-time error  13: Type mismatch`

Answer (score 0):

It returns error because **val1** is defined as long and cell value is a string. I removed *&* characters from *dim* part. Also merge part is updated.

```
Sub TestCustomMerge()
    Dim row2, row4, val1, val2, val3
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    row2 = 2
    row4 = 4
    val1 = Cells(row2, 1).Value
    val2 = Cells(row2, 2).Value
    Range(Cells(row2, 1), Cells(row4 - row2, 1)).Merge
    Cells(row2, 1).Value = val1
    Range(Cells(row2, 2), Cells(row4 - row2, 2)).Merge
    Cells(row2, 2).Value = val2
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I run this program ? Also can you please bried why we are doing `Cells(row4 - row2, 1))` ?

Comment: Should not it be simple `Range(A2, A4).Merge` but even this is not working ?

Comment: @user3198603 **1st question:** A2 and A3 cells are merged in the screenshot. however, you used 4 (_row4_) in your code. So I thought you wanted to merge cells A2 and A3 by using 2 and 4. `row4 - row2` part is only maths. you can modify it as much as you want. **2nd question:** `Range("A2", "A4").Merge` works. You should not forget quotes because they are string.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use pivot table? if your data is huge, you'll get some problems to run this vba script over multiple rows